# Скрипт типа Аккордеон на js

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать ниспадающий блок на подобие аккордеона.
Пытаюсь интегрировать вот такой скрипт:

```
`var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("workplace_td icon pointer");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
`
```

Но не могу никак заставить его открываться на ссылку. 
Вот тут по идее должен исполняться скрипт, но я ума не приложу как это сделать:

```
        <div class="td_6">
            <div class="workplace_td icon pointer">
                <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так у вас же не задан ни `display:none`, ни `display:block`, по которым выполняется проверка условия.

```
<div class="td_6">
    <div class="workplace_td icon pointer">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div style="display:block;">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```